# How to define self referencing extendable interface with optional type?

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's say I have menu interface:

```
interface IMenuBase {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    items: IMenuBase[]; <- children 
}
```

Now I want to extend it. For this purpose I define another interface:

```
interface ICustomMenu extend IMenuBase {
    concrete: string;
}
```

The probleme is, `items` is still an IMenuBase.

I've tried to solve it this way:

```
interface IMenuBase<T extends IMenuBase<T>> {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    items: T[];
}

interface ICustomMenu extends IMenuBase<ICustomMenu> {
    concrete: string;
}
```

But now I want to be able to use IMenuBase without type.
Here is my [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IMenuBase%3CT%20extends%20IMenuBase%3CT%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20items%3A%20T%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ICustomMenu%20extends%20IMenuBase%3CICustomMenu%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20concrete%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20testBase%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20IMenuBase%3B%0D%0AtestBase.items%5B0%5D.items%5B0%5D.id%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20testConcrete%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20ICustomMenu%3B%0D%0AtestConcrete.items%5B0%5D.items%5B0%5D.concrete%3B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possibilities. You can go with your current solution of making the base class generic and add a default for the type parameter:

```
interface IMenuBase<T extends IMenuBase<T> = IMenuBase<T>> {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    items: T[];
}

interface ICustomMenu extends IMenuBase<ICustomMenu> {
    concrete: string;
}

const testBase = {} as IMenuBase;
testBase.items[0].items[0].id;

const testConcrete = {} as ICustomMenu;
testConcrete.items[0].items[0].concrete;
```

The above code has the issue that it only works for up to 3 levels (I think this the recursive-ness of the default is limited by the compiler)

A better option might be to use polymorphic `this` to specify that the children are of the same type as the current type, whatever that type may be:

```
interface IMenuBase {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    items: this[];
}

interface ICustomMenu extends IMenuBase {
    concrete: string;
}

const testBase = {} as IMenuBase;
testBase.items[0].items[0].id;

const testConcrete = {} as ICustomMenu;
testConcrete.items[0].items[0].concrete;
```

Comment: `this` - excelent. Great idea. Thanks! :)

Comment: Did you test the first proposed solution? I get the following error when I try it: "Type parameter defaults can only reference previously declared type parameters."

Comment: @RaxAdaam worked 4  years ago when I posted it sees like TS version churn was not kind to it